# Unity.ResolutionFailedException - Resolution of the dependency failed

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have the following code:

```
 public static IEngine CreateEngine()
    {
        UnityContainer container = Unity.LoadUnityContainer(DefaultStrategiesContainerName);
        IEnumerable<IStrategy> strategies = container.ResolveAll<IStrategy>();
        ITraderProvider provider = container.Resolve<ITraderProvider>();

        return new Engine(provider, new List<IStrategy>(strategies));
    }
```

and the config:

```
<unity>  <typeAliases>
<typeAlias alias="singleton" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
<typeAlias alias="weakRef" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
<typeAlias alias="Strategy" type="ADTrader.Core.Contracts.IStrategy, ADTrader.Core" />
<typeAlias alias="Trader" type="ADTrader.Core.Contracts.ITraderProvider, ADTrader.Core" />  </typeAliases>  <containers>
<container name="strategies">
  <types>
    <type type="Strategy" mapTo="ADTrader.Strategies.ThreeTurningStrategy, ADTrader.Strategies" name="1" />
    <type type="Trader" mapTo="ADTrader.MbTradingProvider.MBTradingProvider, ADTrader.MbTradingProvider" />
  </types>
</container>  </containers></unity>
```

I am getting the following exception:

> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type = "ADTrader.Core.Contracts.ITraderProvider",
>   name = "". Exception message is: The current build operation (build
>   key Build Key[ADTrader.MbTradingProvider.MBTradingProvider, null])
>   failed: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt. (Strategy type
>   BuildPlanStrategy, index 3) --->
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildFailedException: The current
>   build operation (build key Build
>   Key[ADTrader.MbTradingProvider.MBTradingProvider, null]) failed:
>   Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt. (Strategy type
>   BuildPlanStrategy, index 3) ---> System.AccessViolationException:
>   Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.    at
>   MBTCOMLib.MbtComMgrClass.EnableSplash(Boolean bEnable)    at
>   ADTrader.MbTradingProvider.MBTradingProvider..ctor()    at
>   BuildUp_ADTrader.MbTradingProvider.MBTradingProvider(IBuilderContext )
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.Builder.BuildUp(IReadWriteLocator
>   locator, ILifetimeContainer lifetime, IPolicyList policies,
>   IStrategyChain strategies, Object buildKey, Object existing)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name) 
>   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerBase.ResolveT    at
>   ADTrader.Engine.EngineFactory.CreateEngine()

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of your `MbTradingProvider.MBTradingProvider` calls a method on a COM object (assuming from the name), `MBTCOMLib.MbtComMgrClass.EnableSplash`. This method has a bug in it, causing wrong memory address to be written.